# How can I integrate updates to a installation CD/DVD?

Tags: installation, boot, usb-drive, updates, cd

I have this question about how to integrate updates to a installation CD/USB, like a slipstream in Windows. Is this possible to make?

Thanks for answering.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit) is a tool that helps you customizing official Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu)  to your needs. You can add any package to the live system like, for example, language packs, applications, etc.

You can install it via Ubuntu Software Center.

Features:

Create bootable LiveCD with predefined languages based upon an original Ubuntu/Kubuntu live CD using graphical wizard.

Build live CD with special features using scripts. It is possible to customize the root filesystem (for example install/remove packages), ISO contents (add/remove docs, change names) and initrd (add modules to boot, change boot sequence).